# Slide to show more content overflowed on div

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to do a fully customized Facebook "Like-Box". I want to have this fixed width div and be able to slide left or right to show more faces (I would prefer ajax, but that doesn't seem possible, or does it?).

If there's no ajax way to LOAD more faces, I would like to pre-load, let's say, 50 faces, on this small div and press left or right to slide more content (faces) from inside the div.

[image: Facebook Like-box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in javascript by setting the scrollLeft property of the div.  Or if using jQuery, you can use the scrollLeft method.

IE: `$("#myDiv").scrollLeft( 250 );`

jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: Don't know why but this is working only the for the 1st time a click.. is there something like slideLeft on jQuery? (for animation)

Comment: the # in the call is an absolute number.  If you want to scroll again, you need to ADD to the current scroll left: $('#myDiv').scrollLeft(250+$('#myDiv').scrollLeft());

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar like this:

```
    slideContent: function(obj) {
        var margin = $(".myDiv").width();
        margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
        margin = margin * -1;

        $(".tabslider").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: margin + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 300
        });
```

Full code here:
http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/tabbed/

That way it simply adds margin to the slide left distance